# What software can I use to easily make this product sheet template?

Tags: software-recommendation, page-layout, layout

I don't really do design but have been assigned to make a product sheet for a lot of different products in this style:

[image]

[Original PDF here](https://engelmanns.se/wp-content/uploads/132030-Appenzeller-Creamy-NO92.pdf)

Do any of you have any tips on what software to use to make this? I've tried Powerpoint but it didn't end up well.

Comment: Illustrator or Indesign probably could be a software of choice, but the thing is: if you don't do design there's a chance it won't end up well in any software. A person that does design can do it in Excel.

Comment: If you want free software, Scribus for page layout, and Inkscape for vector graphics. These aren't easy software however.  Maybe you could try something simpler like LibreOffice Draw?

Comment: Adobe InDesign... no question.

Answer (score 1):

Two parts:

**I. The software is about the final product.**

Do you need it to be mass printed? or it is just for electronic use, or to be printed in the office?

If it is to be mass printed you need a program that makes a suitable output.

- Illustrator, Corel Draw, Affinity designer.

If you need "for a lot of different" products you probably need to automate the process using some excel files and data variables.

- Excel or Libre office, Indesign, Corel Draw, Probably Scribus.

If you do not need to be mass printed

- Excel + Word or PowerPoint or similar, Inkscape.

**II. It is not about the software**

If you want to spend time and effort, besides potentially some money wasted, start from scratch, but probably you need to hire a designer that knows how to do this, saving you time.

Even PowerPoint has some methods to extract variable data. But you need to focus on what is your real problem. "it didn't end up well" needs to be more specific. Design? Data-merge? Print?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with Adobe InDesign or Affinity Publisher if you're going for high quality print. If not you could do that in Photoshop or Word.